# it is or they are

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, existentials

1. We need a warm-kind heart and self-acceptance because it is the key to our success.
2. We need a warm-kind heart and self-acceptance because they are the key to our success.

Which is correct? "It is" or "they are"?

Comment: How many things are _warm-kind heart_ and _self-acceptance?_

Answer (score 2):

You are mentioning

> 1) a warm heart
>   2) self acceptance

since they are two separate things, the verb needs to be plural

> We need a warm-kind heart and self-acceptance because they are the keys to our success.

Comment: 'Key' should be made plural, too.